# React changing parent state during input onChange getting stuck

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a huge form which is made of atleast 50 inputs.
I have wrote a function in the form component that will save the value of the input to the form state:

PARENT FUNCTION

```
saveToState(details) {
    const { company } = this.state;
    company[details.part][details.element] = details.value;
    this.setState({ company });
  }
```

PASSING TO CHILD COMPONENT (INPUT)

```
<FieldInput
  label="Name (as shown) *"
  part="information"
  element="displayName"
  saveToState={this.saveToState}
/>
```

Here is the Input component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class FieldInput extends Component {
  render() {
    const { label, part, element, saveToState } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="field">
        <label>{label}</label>
        <div className="ui input">
          <input
            type="text"
            name={`${part}[${element}]`}
            onChange={(e) => saveToState({
              part,
              element,
              value: e.target.value
            })}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In result whenever I type something in the input It's taking it 200-300ms to really display what I wrote in the input, the state is getting updates instantly but whenever I type a character I set the new state of the parent form and update it which updates the whole component. The only way i found around it is to use `saveToState` within the parent component without passing it down. but that would require 1000's of line of code, Is there any way around this? Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that the `input`s are uncontrolled (ie. change in state does not re-render the `input`). How's the performance without `onChange` all together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are alot of ways you can solve this problem. The easiest one and the fastest one is to use `onBlur` instead of `onChange` that way `setState` will happen not when you key pressing in the input but when the input loses focus.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class FieldInput extends Component {
  render() {
    const { label, part, element, saveToState } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="field">
        <label>{label}</label>
        <div className="ui input">
          <input
            type="text"
            name={`${part}[${element}]`}
            onBlur={(e) => saveToState({
              part,
              element,
              value: e.target.value
            })}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```